# How do I dynamically add a stylesheet using Dart?

Tags: dom, dart, stylesheet, dart-html

I know in Javascript how to dynamically add a stylesheet.
This can be done using the following code:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
```

But when I try the same using Dart (https://www.dartlang.org/), like this:

```
CssStyleSheet sheet = document.createElement('style');
```

Then the Dart-editor tells me *"A value of type Element cannot be assigned to a variable of type CssStyleSheet"*.

I also tried it like this:

```
CssStyleSheet styleSheet = new CssStyleSheet();
```

But that gives me the warning *"The class CssStyleSheet does not have a default constructor"*

And this:

```
CssStyleSheet sheet = DomImplementation.createCssStyleSheet('mySheet', '');
```

Gives met *"Instance member 'createCssStyleSheet' cannot be accessed using static access"*.


So my question is: how do I create a CssStyleSheet in Dart, such that I can use methods like `insertRule(rule, index)` and `deleteRule(index)`?

Kind regards,
Hendrik

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create CSS keyframe rule in Dart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968777/how-to-create-css-keyframe-rule-in-dart)

Comment: Thanks for the notice. This is not a duplicate, because I want to create a new stylesheet dynamically, while your link points to a question where an already existing stylesheet is used.

Comment: Ok, I had the impression this is not necessary.
Can you try `document.head.append(new StyleElement());` and then continue with the example of the 'duplicate'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried it and it worked for me:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;

main () {
  dom.document.head.append(new dom.StyleElement());
  final styleSheet = dom.document.styleSheets[0] as dom.CssStyleSheet;
  final rule = 'div { color: blue; }';
  styleSheet.insertRule(rule, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works, but dom.document.styleSheets[0] does not return the newly created styleSheet. I added my own solution as another answer.

Comment: That's interesting because without the first line I get a RangeError when I try to access `dom.document.styleSheets[0]`. Glad you found something that worked for you.

Comment: Maybe you used the code in an empty document where the only stylesheet is your dynamically added stylesheet (or nothing if you removed the first line). I used it in a document where there were already a couple of stylesheets loaded and then ```dom.document.styleSheets[0]``` returns the first stylesheet that was already loaded.

Comment: You are right. I thought you got the same RangeError when you wrote that the solution in 'duplicate' is not working for you. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 7):

The answer of Günter Zöchbauer helped me find a solution (see my comment on his answer).
This works:

```
import 'dart:html';

main () {
  // create a stylesheet element
  StyleElement styleElement = new StyleElement();
  document.head.append(styleElement);
  // use the styleSheet from that
  CssStyleSheet sheet = styleElement.sheet;

  final rule = 'div { border: 1px solid red; }';
  sheet.insertRule(rule, 0);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your decision - for some reasons i have empty <style></style> element added to head. Don`t you had same expirience?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs to add an external stylesheet, this is how you do it.

```
LinkElement link = document.head.append(LinkElement());
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "/site.css";
```