# Is there a way to dynamically insert a CSS/style fragment into the DOM using DART?

Tags: dart

As with some of the other Dart questions that have been posed about loading and injecting HTML fragment into the DOM, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do something similar with CSS/style fragments that I download via AJAX.

Trying to insert it as a style tag in HTML just results in the message:

```
Removing disallowed element <STYLE>  // note: original text is lower-case 'style'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524190

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with the above problem for a while, I came upon the solution myself. I post it here in case it helps others or in case someone has suggestions for better methods.

The problem I found was that I was injecting the CSS style element into the DOM container element as "innerHtml" - which was being rejected. I found that if I specifically created a style tag element I could then insert the CSS as "text", like this:

This code takes the HTML and CSS fragments that it downloads from the AJAX server and then inserts them into new elements on my master "screen" element. In this example, the HTML gets inserted into a basic container 'div' element as innerHtml, and the CSS gets injected into a style element as text. They then both get attached to the parent element and the stylized HTML instantly pops on screen.

```
var screen = querySelector('#myScreen');     
var container = new DivElement();
container.innerHtml = html;
var styleElement = new Element.tag('style');
styleElement.text = css;
screen.children.add(styleElement);
screen.children.add(container);
```