# Dynamically update a stylesheet using dart within a template in a polymer-element

Tags: html, css, dom, dart, dart-polymer

I am dynamically updating my stylesheet as described in [this other SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524190/how-do-i-dynamically-add-a-stylesheet-using-dart). In general it works great, but it doesn't for the HTML DOM tags I have within my polymer element template (e.g. I can not change the style of `.above-board`).

Do you have an idea how could I make it work? Apart from embedding the style changes directly in the HTML for each element instead of using classes. Showing the code below (tried to remove as much non-relevant code as possible):

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    ...

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <panepond-board class="player1"></panepond-board>
        </div>
        <script type="application/dart" src="board.dart"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### component.html

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html"/>
<polymer-element name="panepond-board">
    <template>
        <div class="above-board">
            <input type="button" value="toggle config" on-click="{{toggleConfig}}" class="update"/><br/>
            <label>score: {{totalScore}}</label>
        </div>

        ...

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="board.css"/>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
<script type="application/dart" src="board.dart"></script>
```

### board.dart

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import "package:range/range.dart";
import 'config.dart';

main() {
    initPolymer().run(() {
        Polymer.onReady.then((_) {
            var board1 = querySelector('.player1');
            window.onKeyDown.listen( (e) {
                board1.actOnKeyDown(new String.fromCharCodes([e.keyCode]));
            });
            board1.init();
        });
    });
}


@CustomTag('panepond-board')
class Board extends PolymerElement {
    @observable Config config = new Config(6);
    Board.created() : super.created();

    void init() {
        config.loadCSS();
    }
```

### config.dart

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';

class Config extends Observable {
        num width;
        Config(w) : width = w;

        void loadCSS() {
            StyleElement styleElement = new StyleElement();
            document.head.append(styleElement);
            CssStyleSheet sheet = styleElement.sheet;
            final rule1 = '.above-board { border: 1px solid blue; }';
            sheet.insertRule(rule1, sheet.cssRules.length); //this doesn't show any effect
            final rule2 = '.main { border: 1px solid red; }';
            sheet.insertRule(rule2, sheet.cssRules.length); //this works fine
        }
}
```

If I manually append `.above-board{border: 1px solid blue;}` on `board.css`, the rule will work as expected (i.e. it will display the blue border). Otherwise, doing it programmatically (see `rule1` above) has no effect.

Comment: How did you try to access the styles? Please add the code. What doesn't work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Where do you add it if you add it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
document.head.append(styleElement);
```

should be

```
document.querySelector('panepond-board.player1')
    .shadowRoot.append(styleElement);
```

Comment: If I just replace that, I get an error `Uncaught Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError: Cannot call "get$shadowRoot" (this.get$shadowRoot is not a function)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, this works only for code within the element itself. I updated my answer.