# Add a nth-child style programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, dart

I want to follow the pattern set out in [this blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/03/15/animating-lists-with-css-3-transitions/) which uses the following css rules to specify where the items should appear:

```
.items li { 
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
.items li:nth-child(1)  { transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0); }
.items li:nth-child(2)  { transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0); }
.items li:nth-child(3)  { transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0); }
```

However, I don't know how many items will be in the list so I'd rather not hard-code in say 30 lines like the above and be limited to 30 list items.  Instead, I'd like to add a style rule every time an item is added, which means I can have an unlimited number of list items.

I've tried various approaches but can't figure out how to programmatically add such style rules dynamically.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm writing the app in Dart but a Javascript solution would be equally welcome.

**Update**

See below for the accepted answer that got me on the right track. It uses jquery so I've included below a version for anyone like me who is using Dart.  The Dart version uses [How do I dynamically add a stylesheet using Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524190/how-do-i-dynamically-add-a-stylesheet-using-dart) which I've just found - I don't know how I missed it earlier.  Thanks all for helping.

```
import 'dart:html' as Html;
void main(){
  Html.StyleElement styleElement = new Html.StyleElement();
  Html.document.head.append(styleElement);
  Html.CssStyleSheet sheet = styleElement.sheet;
  final rule = 'div { border: 1px solid red; }';
  sheet.insertRule(rule, 0);
}
```

Comment: is this pattern as static as it looks? there may not be a reason to do it in javascript at all. have you heared of sass/scss/less ? Browsers do not like style modifications. the mentioned tools make generating styles very easy.

Comment: I haven't used sass/scss or less but from what I can tell they don't do what I need here.  The basic problem is that I need a style for **each** of an **unknown** number of list items so I need to add a style each time I add an item to the list.  I don't think sass/scss or less helps with that?

Comment: well. scss allows you to define a template of the css you want to generate and you can execute it x times simply by passing a constant. you could set the constant to 2000. that way there is no javascript executed at all and your browser will be happy because loading the styles will be a load+cache once action. modifying styles most certainly will trigger the browser to redo the layout, which you want to avoid at all costs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a stylesheet and add the CSS-rule to it.

```
addChild = function(i) {
  var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
  var rule = '.items li:nth-child(' + i + ')  { transform: translate3d(0, ' + (i*100) + '%, 0); }';
  styleSheet.insertRule(rule, 1);
}
```

This would add a CSS-rule to the first stylesheet that is found in the stylesheet-array and add the rule at the beginning of the stylesheet. You can also look for another stylesheet or create a new one.

For further information have a look [here](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets).

Comment: Thanks - this was what I was looking for or at least got me on the right track.  I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer but see my edit above which sets out a Dart solution and a link to another stackoverflow question which also deals with it.  Don't know why I didn't find that one earlier - I did look.  Anyway, many thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but this jsfiddle uses jQuery to loop through each list item you have and adds the corresponding css, in increments of 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ub4hj1o/

Here is the jquery.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.items li').each( function(i){
   var child = i + 1;
    var trans = i + "00%";
    var cssval = 'translate3d(0, ' + trans + ', 0)';
    $(this).css('transform',cssval);
});
});
```

This is all you need for the CSS now.

```
.items li { 
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you are also trying to add or remove them dynamically, here is a jsfiddle for that. Note that I did take away the translate3d and position:absolute CSS styles because it is much more simple to add things dynamically if the position is relative. If you're looking for something different let us know. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/2ub4hj1o/1/

Comment: Thanks - the second version is close to what I want becuase it handles dynamically adding items.  The translate3d and relative positions are important (see the article I mentioned which I think is quite interesting) but I'm sure your suggestion could be easily adapted to include those aspects.  However, I'm really looking for a jquery-less solution (sorry - I should have said that).

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you found what you were looking for. Just for fun, you might also want to take a look at JQuery's sortable if you ever end up using JQuery. It's similar to what this example does. https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var li = $(".items li");
    var add = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<li.length;i++){
        $(li[i]).css({"transform":"translate3d(0, "+add+"%, 0)"});
        add +=100;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: That approach would probably work but I want a jquery-less solution (I should have said that).