# styling "pseudo-element" using Dart lang

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm building a ctusom element with DART, and styling it without using seperate css file, using the ..style as below:

```
    innerInput = new InputElement()
    ..style.color= '#FF8F66'
    ..style.fontFamily='openSansItalic';
```

I want to use "pseudo-element" styling, like styling the 'placeholder', 'before', 'after' ,... is there a way to do it using dart, or I've to use separate css file, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems these can only be read using code `innerInput.getComputedStyle(':after').content` but not changed but you can create stylesheet rules by code (like the one built from CSS) [How to create CSS keyframe rule in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968777)